# Unix recursive directory listing with full pathname of file and filesize

Tags: linux, filesystems

I'm trying list all files (recursively) with their full path name (including name of the file) followed by their size in bytes. I do not need any '.', '..' entries.

I dont think anything in the 'ls' options would work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
find full_path_to_your_directory -type f -printf '%p %s\n'
```

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, you'll need to put in the full path to "your_directory" there, not just the relative path, or the output will have relative paths too.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question `[unix]` and not `[linux]`, you may not have GNU `find` and its `-printf` option. In that case, this command may work for you:

```
find /dir/to/start/from -type f -ls
```

Comment: whoops sorry - its actually redhat linux that i'm using...!